Azure DocumentIntelligence Java SDK returning 404
I am playing around with Azure's DocumentIntelligence service and I am trying to create a simple example using their Java SDK as mentioned in this piece of documentation. I have created a very minimal code example just to get a feel for it, only attempting to get paragraphs out of the document in question. The code sample is the following:
public class DocumentIntelligenceApp {

    private static final String ENDPOINT = System.getenv("DOCUMENT_INTELLIGENCE_ENDPOINT");
    private static final String KEY      = System.getenv("DOCUMENT_INTELLIGENCE_KEY");
    private static final String MODEL_ID = "prebuilt-layout";

    public static void main(String... args) {

        try {
            var client = new DocumentIntelligenceClientBuilder()
                    .credential(new AzureKeyCredential(KEY))
                    .endpoint(ENDPOINT)
                    .buildClient();

            var request = new AnalyzeDocumentRequest().setUrlSource("https://s29.q4cdn.com/175625835/files/doc_downloads/test.pdf");

            var poller = client.beginAnalyzeDocument(MODEL_ID,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    request);

            var res = poller.getFinalResult();

            res.getParagraphs().forEach(documentParagraph -> {
                System.out.println("Paragraph: ");
                System.out.println(documentParagraph.getContent());
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

 }

Whenever I try to run this though I am met with the following exception:
com.azure.core.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: Status code 404, "{"error":{"code":"404","message":"Resource not found"}}"
    at com.azure.core.implementation.http.rest.RestProxyBase.instantiateUnexpectedException(RestProxyBase.java:398)
    at com.azure.core.implementation.http.rest.SyncRestProxy.ensureExpectedStatus(SyncRestProxy.java:133)
    at com.azure.core.implementation.http.rest.SyncRestProxy.handleRestReturnType(SyncRestProxy.java:210)
    at com.azure.core.implementation.http.rest.SyncRestProxy.invoke(SyncRestProxy.java:86)
    at com.azure.core.implementation.http.rest.RestProxyBase.invoke(RestProxyBase.java:124)
    at com.azure.core.http.rest.RestProxy.invoke(RestProxy.java:95)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy3.analyzeDocumentSync(Unknown Source)
    at com.azure.ai.documentintelligence.implementation.DocumentIntelligenceClientImpl.analyzeDocumentWithResponse(DocumentIntelligenceClientImpl.java:304)
    at com.azure.ai.documentintelligence.implementation.DocumentIntelligenceClientImpl.lambda$beginAnalyzeDocumentWithModel$6(DocumentIntelligenceClientImpl.java:511)
    at com.azure.core.util.polling.SyncPoller.lambda$createPoller$0(SyncPoller.java:227)
    at com.azure.core.util.polling.SimpleSyncPoller.<init>(SimpleSyncPoller.java:92)
    at com.azure.core.util.polling.SyncPoller.createPoller(SyncPoller.java:196)
    at com.azure.core.util.polling.SyncPoller.createPoller(SyncPoller.java:240)
    at com.azure.ai.documentintelligence.implementation.DocumentIntelligenceClientImpl.beginAnalyzeDocumentWithModel(DocumentIntelligenceClientImpl.java:510)
    at com.azure.ai.documentintelligence.DocumentIntelligenceClient.beginAnalyzeDocument(DocumentIntelligenceClient.java:186)
    at com.ariskourt.DocumentIntelligenceApp.main(DocumentIntelligenceApp.java:23)

I have tried searching for this online but I haven't found anything relevant yet. For reference I am using the latest version of the SDK com.azure:azure-ai-documentintelligence:1.0.0-beta.3.
Any ideas would be welcome.

Apparently using the old client com.azure:azure-ai-formrecognizer:4.1.9 works. Still very confusing that the examples contain a new version which doesn't (seemingly).


Azure DocumentIntelligence Java SDK returning 404

I followed this MS-Document and downloaded the dependency with same package azure-ai-documentintelligence:1.0.0-beta.3.
Pom.xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-ai-documentintelligence</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-beta.3</version>
</dependency>

Using the below code with same PDF URL, I can be able to analyze the pdf url using Azure DocumentIntelligence Java SDK.
Code:
public class App {

    private static final String ENDPOINT = "https://venkatintelligence1.cognitiveservices.azure.com/";
    private static final String KEY      = "401a3644aca64c90976298576f79cc0b";
    private static final String MODEL_ID = "prebuilt-layout";

    public static void main(String... args) {

        try {
           DocumentIntelligenceClient documentIntelligenceClient = new DocumentIntelligenceClientBuilder()
            .credential(new AzureKeyCredential(KEY))
            .endpoint(ENDPOINT)
            .buildClient();;
        
        SyncPoller<AnalyzeResultOperation, AnalyzeResult> Poller =
            documentIntelligenceClient.beginAnalyzeDocument(MODEL_ID,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                new AnalyzeDocumentRequest().setUrlSource("https://s29.q4cdn.com/175625835/files/doc_downloads/test.pdf"));

                AnalyzeResult analyzeResult = Poller.getFinalResult();

                analyzeResult.getParagraphs().forEach(documentParagraph -> {
                System.out.println("Paragraph: ");
                System.out.println(documentParagraph.getContent());
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

Output:
Paragraph:
This is a test PDF document. If you can read this, you have Adobe Acrobat Reader installed on your computer.


Reference:
Check this MS-Q&A by VasaviLankipalle-MSFT for similar 404 error.

For me the problem was having my resource in the wrong location.
With the Python SDK "Sweden Central" worked just fine, but with the Java Preview version I had to create a new resource in "West Europe", as mentioned in the "MS-Q&A" thread linked by Venkatesen.
